# Is there any possibility to re-use "Share" and "Follow" feature of sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I am displaying documents in home page using rest api or sp services jquery, where i need to append the "Share" and "Follow" to each document. So Is there any possibility to reuse the "Share" and "Follow" Document Library feature of sharepoint 2013. If you have provided with example It will be great. Thanks in Advance.